# SQL query to check if any from list of values are in either of three columns

Tags: sql, performance, netezza

I have a list of numbers:

```
a = { 100, 1002, 44522, 5332323 }
```

I want to select observations from a table if any of these values { 100, 1002, 44522, 5332323 } are in either column1, column2, or column3 and date is between Jan,1, 2003 and Jan,1,2004.

```
select * from table1
where column1 in a 
  or  column2 in a 
  or column3 in a 
  and date between (Jan,1, 2003 and Jan,1,2004)
```

How do I write an efficient query addressing these conditions?

Comment: Pretty sure the date format there is not going to work in most SQL. Also, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It is largely a question about your data set. Your query seems sound as pseudocode, but making it as efficient as possible is dependent on having the right indexes, and possibly partitions, on your table. What those are is dependent on the size and shape of your data,

Answer (score 3):

I would just recommend adding the list as a pseudo table see below:

```
select a.*
from table1 a inner join
  (select 100 as val
        union all
   select 1002
        union all
   select 44522
        union all
   select 5332323
  ) b
on  (a.column1 =b.val  or  a.column2 = b.val
  or column3 =b.val)
  and date between '2003-01-01' and '2004-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it I suggest you to use (in SQL Server):

```
@a = '100, 1002, 44522, 5332323'  -- a varchar(max)
```

And use it in your query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE (',' + REPLACE(@a, ' ', '') + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(max), column1) + ',%'
   OR ',' + REPLACE(@a, ' ', '') + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(max), column2) + ',%'
   OR ',' + REPLACE(@a, ' ', '') + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(max), column3) + ',%')
  AND CONVERT(varchar, date, 107) BETWEEN 'Jan 1, 2003' AND 'Jan 1, 2004'
```

---

(In Netezza I think this should work)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE (',' || sql_functions..replace(@a, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,' || CAST(column1 AS varchar(20)) || ',%'
   OR  ',' || sql_functions..replace(@a, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,' || CAST(column2 AS varchar(20)) || ',%'
   OR  ',' || sql_functions..replace(@a, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,' || CAST(column3 AS varchar(20)) || ',%')
  AND date ...
```

Comment: I dont have access to SQL Server

Comment: @EzraPolson So you have access to which datatbase? ;).